# How do I setup connection pooling in spring boot for Elasticsearch

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data, connection-pooling

I have created a spring boot application that uses spring boot starter data elasticsearch to connect to elasticsearch. I want to configure this application to setup connection pooling. How do I configure the application.properties to support it?

Answer (score 1):

**Old answer**. Since Boot 2.2, the reactive client doesn't have these options.

[From the docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.x/reference/html/common-application-properties.html):

> spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.*= # Additional properties used to configure the client.

Though it does appear that the default `TransportClient` does pool connections anyway.

Comment: Would you mind updating this? `elasticsearch.properties` currently is not found on the docs.